# Why Apache POI XWPFRun.setFontFamily() for cyrillic works wrong?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I try to `setFontFamily("Arial")` to XWPFRun object with `setText("Привет Hello")` - cyrillic a english. English text will become Arial after this method call, but Russian text will be still at Colibri font family. How to create right font family for cyrillic text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment to `setFontFamily()` says:

> Specifies the fonts which shall be used to display the text contents of this run. Specifies a font which shall be used to format all characters in the ASCII range (0 - 127) within the parent run

To other char try use `CTFonts.setHAnsi`, for example `myXWPFRun.getCTR().getRPr().getRFonts().setHAnsi("Arial");`

See bug https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47148